# Make messages for specific Excel error Messages using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to say if Error 1004 shows up, show message "Message"  and If Error 9, show message "Message2" instead of generic non-descriptor geek speak message for end user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called Error Handling.

See this Example. You can trap the Error Number using `Err.Number`

```
Sub Sample()
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Rest of the code

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 9
            MsgBox "Message1"
        Case 1004
            MsgBox "Message2"
    End Select
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

```
Sub Sample1()
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Rest of the code

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox GetErrMsg(Err.Number)
End Sub

Sub Sample2()
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Rest of the code

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox GetErrMsg(Err.Number)
End Sub

Function GetErrMsg(ErNo As Long) As String
    Select Case ErNo
        Case 9
            GetErrMsg = "Message1"
        Case 1004
            GetErrMsg = "Message2"
        Case Else
            GetErrMsg = "Message3"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Sweet and simple, the best type of code, thanks :) Just one question, does this have to go into each section, or can this be created as it's own module?

Comment: It has to go into each section. But you can write a common procedure on what you want to do for example... see the updated code...

Comment: I just tried this, and I'm getting a "Label Not Defined" message.

Comment: I got it working, just about a minute ago, don't need help there, but I figured out another "issues" if I have a long message, how do I break it up?

Comment: Create a new post and ask a question there?

Comment: that is what I thought, but with how we were talking about message here, I figured :) Conciser it done in the next few min.